# Get all relations through manyToMany relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have `User`, `Account` and `Item` models.

`Account` has many `User` relations, and `User` has many `Account` relations. These are defined as many to many.

An `Account` has many `Item` relations, and I am wondering how to fetch all `Item` on all `Account` relations for a `User`.

```php
// User.php:
public function accounts()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany( Account::class );
}

// Account.php
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany( User::class );
}

// Item.php
public function account()
{
  return $this->belongsTo( Account::class );
}
```

Any idea on how to do a call like `auth()->user()->items` or `auth()->user()->accounts()->items` ?

Answer (score 2):

as per your relationship, you can fetch every accounts of a user with every items on each of those accounts as follows:

```php
auth()->user()->accounts()->with('items')->get();
```

for the above statement to work, you need to define `items` relationship on your `Account` model as follows:

```php
//Account.php
public function items()
{
  return $this->hasMany( Item::class );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a direct `BelongsToMany` relationship by "skipping" the `accounts` table:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Item::class,
            'account_user',
            'user_id', 'account_id', null, 'account_id'
        );
    }
}

$items = auth()->user()->items;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list a items with those conditions, start from the item model

```php
$userId = auth()->id();
$items = Item::whereHas('account', function($account) use ($userId) {
    $account->whereHas('users', function($user) use ($userId) {
        $user->where('id','=', $userId);
    });
})->get();
```